# Clean get of 32 bit source code onto a 64 bit machine. Precautions?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit

I'm about to do a clean get of 32 bit source code onto my new Windows 7 64 bit machine. Is there anything special I need to do (switch to 32 bit mode, etc) or will Windows detect this and adapt accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

The "bitness" of the operating system has nothing to do with getting source code. Your IDE determines what the target is of your compile of the source code, and most IDEs now can target either.

In other words, Windows doesn't have to do anything, and neither do you. Your development environment uses the source code, and determines what happens with it. Windows has absolutely nothing to do with it, except to run any resulting executable that's produced if it's compatible with that version of Windows. (And Win64 runs 32-bit applications just fine.)

Just as a note: You can't "switch to 32-bit mode" with a 64-bit operating system. It's always going to be a 64-bit operating system, even if you're running a 32-bit application. The application may not know it's running on a 64-bit OS, but it will be despite it's ignorance of that fact. :)